# WPF binding for a converter not working

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a custom converter that has a DefaultText property. All my converter does is return the DefaultText if the string is null or empty. I can't seem to get it to work though. Here's what I've got. This is the converter class.

```
public class DisplayValueConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "DefaultText",
                                                                                                 typeof ( string ),
                                                                                                 typeof ( DisplayValueConverter ) );

    public string DefaultText
    {
        get { return ( string ) GetValue( DefaultTextProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( DefaultTextProperty, value ); }
    }

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {

        string empty = ( parameter != null ) ? parameter as string : DefaultText;
        return ( value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( value.ToString().Trim() ) ) ? value.ToString() : empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my xaml putting it into use.

```
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="3"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="0,0,10,0" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="DataSource.Payee"
                         Mode="TwoWay"
                         NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"
                         NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"
                         NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <k:DisplayValueConverter DefaultText="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Binding.Converter>
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <vr:RequiredField Label="Payee" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

I've verified that the DataContext has an object, and that the Path works. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @rossisdead - Nothing. I was expecting the databinding engine to first bind the converter property DefaultText, then to attempt the bind the text property on the path DataSource.Payee, but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have an Element named "This"  as specified in your DefaultText binding?

Comment: I think your problem here is that you're expecting the DefaultText property to cause the converter's Convert method to be called. This won't happen since it's unrelated to the TextBox's own binding.  You may be better off setting the TextBox's binding's TargetNullValue or DefaultValue or one of those properties.

Comment: First, check whether break point hits. Second, check is there any binding error in output window. as Wonko the sane said, ensure "This" is in your context.

Comment: Break point is not being hit, however there is an element named "This". It's almost as if the binding engine calls the convert method before attempting to databind the property DefaultText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your use of Binding.ElementName. Because your value converter isn't actually part of the visual or logical tree, the binding engine has no way of knowing what tree it needs to traverse in order to find the element with the matching ElementName.

In this scenario, your best bet is going to be to specifically set the binding's Source property from code behind, or maybe creating a custom markup extension that would grab the right object for you.

Comment: This makes sense. I set the binding in code at it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

just to add comment to the **answer#1** - even if the converter would be in the visual or logical tree you should not assume that `DefaultText` will be set before the execution of `Convert(...)` in the converter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had forgotten that WPF requires that bindings to code-behind values must be explicitly declared as public properties with getters and setters.

So this was failing:

```
public partial class MyPage: Page
{
    public bool ShowLabel;  //No get/set !

    // constructor etc...
}

<Page x:Name="pageName">

    <Label Content="Hello" 
           Visibility="{Binding 
                           Path=ShowLabel, 
                           ElementName=pageName, 
                           Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>

</Page>
```

This was not converting, at all. Breakpoints were not hitting. Nothing.

By adding a getter and setter to the properties I was using, the page recognised the values and the bindings/converter worked as required.

```
public partial class MyPage: Page
{
    public bool ShowLabel { get; set; }
}
```